# Find nearest match of free form address in normalized address data

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am pulling [existing address data](https://www.streamlinedsalestax.org/ratesandboundry/Boundary/) and am trying to understand if there is functionality in postgresql/postgis to perform free-form matching against this address data.

I ideally would like to be able to run a query for something like '100 Foobar St. Atlanta, GA' and get back a ranked list of possible matches similar to how the [Geocode](https://postgis.net/docs/Geocode.html) query works with TIGER data. Any ideas how to accomplish something similar with my own normalized address database?

Comment: https://github.com/pelias/pelias

Comment: This doesn't seem quite like what I am looking for. I'm trying to match an incoming address against a fixed set of potential pre-normalized candidates.